# Error deleting from sql database according to name

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, sql-delete

I have a simple list view filled with string values, when the user long clicks a specific item, he has an option to delete it (in a contextual action mode). The values inside the listview are in an sql database. My "deleteCat " method doesn't seem to work. I have an error ("no such column: *items_name*") whenever I try to delete an item

```
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_delete_cat:

                CategoryDatabase entry = new CategoryDatabase(MainActivity.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.deleteCat(itemClicked);

                List<String> all = entry.getAllCategory();
                lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, all);
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                entry.close();
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
```

databse class:

public class CategoryDatabase {

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBCategory";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "categoryTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public CategoryDatabase(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public CategoryDatabase open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public long createEntry(String category) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public List<String> getAllCategory() {
    List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;

    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            List.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return List;
   }

public void deleteCat(String itemClicked) {
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_CATEGORY + "=" + itemClicked, null);     
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes to your delete query.

`ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_CATEGORY + "= '" + itemClicked +"'", null);`

Otherwise sql thinks it is a column.